# Spiral Matrix algorithm problem

Tags: c#, java, .net

Hey guys,
My code is populating spiral matrix.
It works just fine when rows=columns
but when different it gives an error on the first bent of the spiral!!!
I've tried debugging it with a breakpoint but wasn't able to find anything wrong!
So a few extra tips about my code:
bentCounter looks for when a row or column is filled and if so it swirls the spiral by incrementing j. When j++ the next elements of arrays B and C are used and thus the direction is changed of the indexes p,q of A array!
When we have both filled row followed by column a sub matrix is left so n--; m--;
When j=3 it should be nullified to start a new swirl.
Hope that's clear enough!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //n - quantity of rows, m - quantity of columns
            // p,q - references to current element of The Matrix A[][]
            // p=1, q=3 ----> A[0][3] - the element of crossing first row and fourth column

            int p = 0;
            int q = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int bentCounter = 0;

            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int n = a;
            int m = b;
            int mn = m * n;

            int [,] A = new int [a,b];
            int[] B = new int[] { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
            int[] C = new int[] { 1, 0, -1, 0 };

            for (int i = 0; i < mn ; i++)
            {
                bentCounter++;
                if (bentCounter == n) {j++;}
                if (bentCounter == m + n - 1)
                {
                    if (j == 3) { j = -1; }
                    j++;
                    bentCounter = 0;
                    n--; m--;
                }

                A [p,q] = i;
                p += B[j];
                q += C[j];                              
            }

            for (int r = 0; r < A.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < A.GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + A[r, c] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

10x appreciate your help
BR

Comment: This is homework, right?  I looked at the other questions you've posted and they are consistent with problems you'd see in an intro to CS course.  Maybe you'd like to talk to your TA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing the dimensions the wrong way and going out of bounds, a quick solution is to swap them round so change `int [,] A = new int [a,b]` into

```
int [,] A = new int [b,a];
```

and all is good ;)

**EDIT**: Also changing this line to pad the output gives you a nice square matrix

```
Console.Write(" " + A[r, c].ToString().PadLeft(mn.ToString().Length, ' '));
```

Comment: Thank you!
Would you give me a tip why I'm incrementing them the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You can also change following

`if (bentCounter == n) { j++; }`

to

`if (bentCounter == m) { j++; }`

and it should work fine. The reason is your B and C prefix is organised in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Also, below codes may be useful for those who want to create a spiral matrix with a given size.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter dimension for spiral matrix:");
    int matrisDim = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[,] matris = new int[matrisDim, matrisDim];
    matris.Initialize();

    int apsisIterator = 0, ordinatIterator = 0, sum = 1;
    bool increment = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrisDim; i++)
    {
        matris[apsisIterator, ordinatIterator] = sum;
        if (increment)
        {
            while (apsisIterator + 1 < matrisDim && matris[apsisIterator + 1, ordinatIterator] == 0)
                matris[++apsisIterator, ordinatIterator] = ++sum;

            while (ordinatIterator + 1 < matrisDim && matris[apsisIterator, ordinatIterator + 1] == 0)
                matris[apsisIterator, ++ordinatIterator] = ++sum;
        }
        else
        {
            while (apsisIterator > 0 && matris[apsisIterator - 1, ordinatIterator] == 0)
                matris[--apsisIterator, ordinatIterator] = ++sum;

            while (ordinatIterator > 0 && matris[apsisIterator, ordinatIterator - 1] == 0)
                matris[apsisIterator, --ordinatIterator] = ++sum;
        }
        increment = !increment;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrisDim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrisDim; j++)
            Console.Write(matris[j, i] + "\t");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You can see this codes on Github Gist too: [Gist - C# Spiral Matrix](https://gist.github.com/firateski/2cae02bcd643185b06b96797560338cc)

Answer (score 0):

Try it: It is a 100% dynamic spiral matrix for the user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Row Column :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtbox" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Starting No :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtstartwith" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate Spiral Matrix" OnClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="divsp" runat="server">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            divsp.InnerHtml = "";
            int ignoreMe;
            bool successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(txtbox.Value, out ignoreMe);
            if (successfullyParsed)
            {
                successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(txtstartwith.Value, out ignoreMe);
                if (successfullyParsed)
                {
                    // ...
                }
                else
                {
                    txtstartwith.Value = "0";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtbox.Value = "0";
            }

            if (txtbox.Value != "" && txtbox.Value != "0" && Convert.ToInt32(txtbox.Value) > 0 && txtstartwith.Value != "")
            {
                int N = Convert.ToInt32(txtbox.Value);
                int row = N;
                int column = N;

                int[,] A = new int[N, N];
                int ele = N * N;
                ele = ele + (Convert.ToInt32(txtstartwith.Value) - 1);
                int no = Convert.ToInt32(txtstartwith.Value);

                int a = 0;
                int b = 0;

                int bo = 0;
                int le = 0;

                int loopbreak = 0;
                while (no <= ele)
                {
                    for (; b < N; b++)
                    {
                        A[a, b] = no;
                        if (no == ele)
                        {
                            loopbreak = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            no++;
                        }

                    }
                    if (loopbreak == 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (b == N)
                    {
                        b = N - 1;
                        for (; a < b; a++)
                        {
                            int i = a + 1;

                            A[i, b] = no;
                            if (no == ele)
                            {
                                loopbreak = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                no++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (loopbreak == 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (a == N - 1)
                    {
                        for (; b > le; b--)
                        {
                            int i = b - 1;
                            A[a, i] = no;
                            if (no == ele)
                            {
                                loopbreak = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                no++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (loopbreak == 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (a == N - 1 && b == bo)
                    {
                        for (; a > le + 1; a--)
                        {
                            int i = a - 1;
                            A[i, b] = no;
                            if (no == ele)
                            {
                                loopbreak = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                no++;
                            }
                        }
                        b = b + 1;
                    }
                    N = N - 1;
                    bo = bo + 1;
                    le = le + 1;
                }
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();


                str.Append("<table>");
                for (int m = 0; m < row; m++)
                {
                    str.Append("<tr>");
                    for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)
                    {
                        str.Append("<td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>" + A[m, k].ToString() + "</td>");
                    }
                    str.Append("</tr>");
                }
                str.Append("</table>");
                divsp.InnerHtml = str.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
```